# Create a pivot table in Power BI with dates instead of aggregate values?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table of companies with descriptive data about where we are in the sales stage with the company, and the date we entered that specific stage. As can be seen below, the stages are rows in a Process Step column

[image]

My objective is to pivot this column so each Process Step is a column, with a date below it, as shown in excel:

[image]

I tried to edit the query and pivot the column upon loading it, but for the "aggregate value" column, no matter which column I use as the values column, it results in some form of error

Comment: Why not just use the matrix visual? Pivoting the data in the query is usually the opposite of what you should be trying to do.

Comment: @W.B. There are repeat client codes that should be unique values, like a primary key. This has made it very difficult for me to do date analytics. For example, if I want to subtract date submitted by the date we exported, I get errors because there's a client code in one row for date submitted, and a client code in another row for the export, and the measure. It makes it near impossible for me to figure out how to do any analytics on the data in that format

Comment: Perhaps if you described your actual goal instead of your attempted solution, someone would be able to come up with something. Is the Excel pivot table your desired end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be not to pivot the table in the query and use measures to get dates that you want. The benefit of not doing so is that you are able to perform all sorts of other analytics. For instance, Sankey chart would be hard to do properly with pivoted table.

To get the pivot table you are showing from Excel, it's as simple as using matrix visual in Power BI and putting Client code in rows and Process Step in Columns, then Effective date in values.

If you need to perform calculations between stages, it's also not too difficult. For instance, you can create a meausure that shows only dates at certain stages, another measure for another stage, and so on. For example:

`Date uploaded = CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Effective Date]), FILTER(Table, Table[Process Step] = "Upload"))`

`Date exported = CALCULATE(MAX(Table[Effective Date]), FILTER(Table, Table[Process Step] = "Export"))`

`Time upload to export = DATEDIFF([Date uploaded], [Date exported], DAY)`

These measures will work in the context of client and assuming there is only one date for the upload step (but no Process step in rows or columns). If another scenario is needed, perhaps a different approach could be taken.

Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: This answers my question completely. I simply wanted the pivot table from Excel, but in Power BI. I tried the above and it worked. The measures work as well. Great response and insight.